# Mouse disappears on virtualbox windows for ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, mouse

Here is the my machine's current setup.

```
windows 8.1 64bit
virtualbox 6.0.24r
ubuntu 18.04.5 server-amd64
```

When I move the mouse over the ubuntu windows, the mouse disappears.
I have tried the following methods but none of them works.

```
1> change mouse from 'PS/2 Mouse' to 'USB Tablet'
2> toggle Disabling Mouse Integration
3> sudo rmmod psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse
4> installed guest addition
5> disabled Enable 3D Acceleration
```

What else should I try?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

That’s normal behaviour unless you have installed a GUI on top of the server. You probably have a black screen with a flashing cursor waiting for you to log in. At least that’s what my Ubuntu test server on VB does.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ponjar said, it seems really the normal behavior...
However, if you get the network and sshd running on guest machine, you can get the mouse working via ssh through terminal (putty for example).